# text rotation : vertical without any absolute , inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve roational text within the div but now able to do it.
Problem facing

1. rotational text should be upside down , like the text should start from bottom, tried to achieve with -90 but it is going upward and crossing the div.
2. no matter what the text, it should be inside the div (currently because it is absolute it is crossing the parent div and is not responsive).
3. Height of the text should always be 100% of parent height.

trying hard to achive this but not getting the clean solution.

```css
.header{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background:gainsboro;
}

.footer{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background:gainsboro;
}

.floatsidebar {
  clear: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
}
  
.sidebarmain {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 99.5%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgrey)
}

.vertical-text {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
header
</div>

<div class="floatsidebar " (click)="_toggleSidebar()">
  <div class="sidebarmain ui-widget-header">
    <div class="vertical-text">622 and 626 All Material Transporter (PC2269)</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
footer
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a good article: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-element to add some padding.

```css
header,footer {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.vertical-text {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.vertical-text:after { 
  content: ''; 
  padding: 45% 0;
  display: block; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<div class="vertical-text">
  some vertical text
</div>

<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

Here is a better approach (taken from http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/) which uses a wrapping span:

```css
.header{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background:gainsboro;
}

.footer{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background:gainsboro;
}

.floatsidebar {
  clear: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
}
  
.sidebarmain {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 99.5%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgrey)
}

 .rotated-text {
     display: inline-block;
     overflow: hidden;

     width: 1.5em;
     line-height: 1.5;
 }
 
 .rotated-text__inner {
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: nowrap;

     transform: translate(0,100%) rotate(-90deg);
     transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
 
  .rotated-text__inner:after {
     content: "";
     float: left;
     margin-top: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
header
</div>

<div class="floatsidebar " (click)="_toggleSidebar()">
  <div class="sidebarmain ui-widget-header">
     <span class="rotated-text">
         <span class="rotated-text__inner">
             622 and 626 All Material Transporter (PC2269)
         </span>
     </span>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
footer
</div>
```

Comment: HI thanks but text should be inside the parent div (sidebarmain ) and parent div has a width of 30px so, this is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writing-mode: vertical-rl` or `writing-mode: vertical-lr`. This CSS property is also supported by all latest browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understand from your question. If it aint what youre looking for. Please comment so i can edit on it.

EDIT

Added jquery to calc the min height of the sidebar

```js
vertTop =  $('.vertical-text').width();
vertTop = vertTop + 60;

$(".sidebarmain").css('height', $('.vertical-text').width());
$('.vertical-text').css('top', vertTop);
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: gainsboro;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: gainsboro;
}

.floatsidebar {
  clear: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.sidebarmain {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgrey)
}

.vertical-text {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  header
</div>

<div class="floatsidebar " (click)="_toggleSidebar()">
  <div class="sidebarmain ui-widget-header">
    <div class="vertical-text">622 and 626 All Material Transporter (PC2269)</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Comment: see your text is crossing to parent div and it is going in header

Comment: You want the div to expand or the text to get smaller

Comment: text should always be inside the div and if the div gets smaller so the text is.

Comment: your code is working fine but as i said the text should be inside the div

Comment: @peepa  did my answer help or did you run into a problem?